# swfobject not executes after ajax call

Tags: ajax, swfobject

I've two php-scripts: the first makes ajax call to the second, which returns javascript code and div for swfobject. I'm calling the second file twice: after loading page(it works ok and I can see swfobjects) and after users' clicking on button(it not works and div just goes blank). 
I suggest that embedSWF works ONLY after pages' loading, because my ajax calling is correct.
But a way must be found! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `swfobject.embedSWF` is designed to work after page load -- it has a built-in domload event handler.

If you don't want swfobject to automatically embed when the page is loaded, use `swfobject.createSWF` instead. The [official documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.createSWF%28attObj,_parObj,_replaceElemIdStr%29) explains how `swfobject.createSWF` works.

EDIT:

After re-reading your post, I see you want to embed a SWF *after* the page has already loaded. `swfobject.embedSWF` can be used in both cases.  Here's [a tutorial and an example](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/load-a-swf-using-javascript-onclick-event/).